# Clear form in another component in Angular6

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a navigation bar in an app with the classic search textbox in it. The way I build my code like so

```
let searchValue : string = 'searchresult?keyword=' + this.searchFormHeader.controls['buscaHeader'].value
this.router.navigateByUrl( searchValue )
this.searchFormHeader.reset()
```

However, when the app arrives at the searchresult page/component, keyword equals *null*
How would I fix my code so that I can clear the textbox and still have the value?

Comment: Are you sure it wasn't null on the first line of code?

Comment: How about storing the value of the input field in your component or a service?

Comment: @FrankModica, yes

Comment: . @Batajus your idea has some merit.

Comment: Create a service (injectable) set it as an app.module provider. inject it into a constructor on whatever component you are using, have a prop within that service.ts and set that then get it again after re-init of the page.